# Git still trying to push ignored and deleted file

Tags: git, github

I have a `.framework` file that is rather large and for some reason Git LFS is not working correctly for it, so I decided to ignore it so that it is not pushed.

1. I added it to my `.gitignore`.
2. I ran these 3 commands from Terminal

   ```
   git rm -r --cached .
   git add .
   git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
   ```
3. I confirmed that the `.framework` is no longer being tracked.
4. When I try to push the commit again, I still get the error that the file is too large.

   ```
   remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large 
   File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
   remote: error: Trace: 6b97634aa8b5de75e8affdcb19d13b98
   remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
   remote: error: File path/to/My.framework/Versions/A/My is 101.13 MB;
   this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
   ```
5. I also deleted the file entirely and it is still attempting to push it.

The `.framework` wasn't always so big. It only recently became >100MB so it used to push without a problem. Is there any solution here?

Comment: Is the large file being pushed now or is it already in the repository and the deletion is failing (which shouldn't be a problem I would think but I could see getting something confused). What does `git show` say about the current commit?

Comment: Are you blocking the *file* `.framework`, or the *directory* `My.framework`?

Comment: The file has been in the repository for a while at about 21 MB, but I recently rebuilt it using Xcode 7 (with `Bitcode` enabled) and it grew to 106 MB. This is when the push started failing. I disabled `Bitcode` and it is now back to 21 MB in size. The push however still fails. @Makoto I ignored the directory `My.framework`.

Answer (score 1):

When you push, you're not just pushing one commit, you're pushing all commits which the remote does not yet have.  I think you did something like this.

```
1. Push/pull to be in sync with the remote.
2. Commit the large file.
3. Delete the large file.
4. Push.
```

Now you're pushing both the commit which added the large file and the commit which deleted it.  They *both* have to be pushed.

You can check what's going to be pushed with `git log --stat origin/master` (assuming the remote is `origin` and the branch is `master`). In particular, commit 6b97634aa8b5de75e8affdcb19d13b98 will be the problem.

If this is the case, you will have to [delete the large file from history](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).

But given that you're having trouble with *both* git-lfs *and* pushing, I think there's something else going on here. I suspect there's *another* large file you're missing. Perhaps you could show your actual repository?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually, I got the `.framework` back down to a reasonable size (21 MB) by disabling `Bitcode`. I removed it from the `.gitignore` and tried a new commit/push but got the same error (saying it is 101.13 MB, even though it is only 21 now). What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @Kevin_TA Like I said, you have to [***delete it from history***](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/). This means rewriting your commits (not making new ones) so that it *never existed* and thus does not need to be pushed. There are more nuanced things you can do than simply obliterating it, like for each historical commit regenerating it without Bitcode so it comes out smaller. These all involve `git filter-branch`, or if there aren't too many commits you can do it manually with `git rebase -i`. That's another question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually ended up making a backup of changes I wanted to keep (the physical files), reset the commit to before I built the `.framework` with `Bitcode`, copied over the files that I had changed and then re-commit and pushed. Finally worked.

Comment: The large file is deleted, so how do you commit that?