# Large file stuck in git commit

Tags: git, github

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage
```

I deleted the file. Below, you can see me trying to push, then trying to remove the file from the cache.

[image]

How do I get rid of this large file so I can push again?

Comment: Now I understand [your comment on my answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466466/git-still-trying-to-push-ignored-and-deleted-file/33466589?noredirect=1#comment60444638_33466589).

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34175916/1256452

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing a work around.

1. Backup all my files to another folder: `cp . ../backup`
2. Remove .git from the backup: `rm -R ..backup/.git`
3. Find the latest good commit on the server and restore to it: `git reset --hard c14809fa`
4. Copy all old files back: `cp ../backup .`

Then just go ahead and commit and push.

Comment: While this works, it loses all history between when the large file was added and the latest commit.

Comment: This worked for me too. In my case I just took backup of the recent files I changed and deleted the local repo and then checked out the code from repo and replaced the latest files from my local back up and then committed. This worked & is also easier.

Answer (score 2):

The file must not just be deleted, it must be removed from history. This is the same procedure you'd follow to remote a sensitive file, such as a password file.

There's a number of ways to do this, the simplest is to [follow the instructions on Github](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).  They show two ways to scrub the file from all commits it is present in.

Answer (score 0):

One good solution that worked for me:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm path/to/your/bigfile' HEAD
```

and then:

```
git push origin master --force
```